# UnsatisfiedLinkError after install, cannot run PLAY

Tags: java, windows-8, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am stuck in the very beginning step. I just install JDK and Play, added all necessary directories in the `PATH` variable. When I run PLAY command, I get the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` mentioned below. Please let me know how to fix this.

Running Windows 8 x64 and the `PATH` directory is

> C:\iSanthosh\dev.tools\play-2.1.3\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;

**Error:**

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Santhosh\AppData\Local\Temp\jline_0_12_2.dll: Access is denied
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at jline.WindowsTerminal.initializeTerminal(WindowsTerminal.java:240)
    at jline.Terminal.setupTerminal(Terminal.java:75)
    at jline.Terminal.getTerminal(Terminal.java:26)
    at jline.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:174)
    at jline.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:169)
    at jline.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:157)
    at play.console.Console$.<init>(Console.scala:15)
    at play.console.Console$.<clinit>(Console.scala)
    at play.console.Console.run(Console.scala:262)
    at play.console.Console.run(Console.scala:259)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:55)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:69)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Santhosh\AppData\Local\Temp\jline_0_12_2.dll: Access is denied
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your permissions on the folder, or you can use [sudo](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_sudo.htm)

```
sudo play
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am using Windows and I have update the folder with full permission. Any other thoughts

Comment: Some more details here. I tried to uninstall everything and re-installed. Following is the error log after typing PLAY command.  Getting net.java.dev.jna jna 3.2.3 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-jna
        confs: [default]
        1 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (838kB/17ms)
Getting play console_2.9.2 2.1.3 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
        confs: [default]
        29 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (5976kB/96ms)
Getting Scala 2.9.2 (for console)...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
        confs: [default]